# I need reset my custom timer to 0 seconds and restart interval only by using rxjs operators

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

I have next code, but it`s not working. By click "reset" button it should setTime to "0" in state and restart interval, not to stop... maybe i should use "fromEvent" instead of "Subject". It seems to add some rxjs operators to observable$...

```
let observable$ = interval(1000)
const actionReset$ = new Subject ();

function customTimer () {
  const [ time, setTime] = useState (0);
  const [ timerOn, setTimerOn ] = useState (false);
  const [ resetClick, setResetClick ] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {  
  let subscription = observable$.pipe(   
    repeatWhen(() => actionReset$),   
  ).subscribe(result =>{
    if (timerOn) {
      setTime(result+1);      
    } else {
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [timerOn]);

return (
    <div className="mainBlock">
//....//
        {!timerOn && (
        <button onClick={() => setTimerOn(true)}>Start</button>
        )}
        { timerOn && (
        <button onClick={onStopClick}>Stop</button>
        )}
        { time > 0 && (
        <button onClick={() => actionReset$}>Reset</button>
        )}   
      </div>  
);
}

export default customTimer;
```

Answer (score 0):

`repeatWhen` is not the right operator for this job.

`repeat` operators are for when a source completes if you want to resubscribe to them. `repeatWhen` is just a more versatile version where you can specify when to repeat the subscription based on another observable, but again - This will happen only after the source completes.

I think this should work for you:

```js
useEffect(() => {  
  let subscription = actionReset$.pipe(
    startWith(null),
    switchMap(() => observable$),
  ).subscribe(result =>{
    if (timerOn) {
      setTime(result+1);
    } else {
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  });
  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [timerOn]);
```

In here I'm creating an observable based on actionReset$ with a switchMap, so that every time actionReset emits it will close the previous subscription to `observable$` and open a new one. `startWith` is needed for the initial subscription.